# TypeScript .entries() does not exist on type 'DOMTokenList'

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vite

I am using vue3, vite and ts. I have a porblem with DOMTokenList. I want to use `.entries()` method but ts says `Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'DOMTokenList'`

This is my tsconfig file

```json
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue", "main.d.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "src/core/types"],
    "ignoreDeprecations": "5.0",
    "lib":["DOM","ESNext"]
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Also I am using `.enties()` function to extend DOMTokenList

```js
DOMTokenList.prototype.removeStartWith = function(prefix:string){
    this.remove(...Array.from(this.entries()).map(([,c]) => c).filter(c => c.startsWith(prefix)))
}
```

I tried previous ECMA (ES2019) versions but I didn't get any result. How can I solve that? Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue; the relevant definition exists at [dom.iterable.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/6f7704e0e2024850a4151dd81c10606bafe9e34f/src/lib/dom.iterable.d.ts#L12) and should be present according to your `lib`.  Works fine for me.  Could you provide a [mre], possibly a web IDE project?  Otherwise I don't see how we can help you other than general debugging advice: how sure are you that `tsc` is actually consulting that `tsconfig.json`, etc?

Comment: Based on your comment, I added the `"DOM.Iterable"` lib. And problem solved. I was thinking that the `"DOM"` lib contains "Iterable". Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @jcalz comment, I added the `"DOM.Iterable"` lib. And problem solved. I was thinking that the `"DOM"` lib contains "Iterable". But it didn't contain.

```json
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue", "main.d.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "src/core/types"],
    "ignoreDeprecations": "5.0",
    "lib":["DOM","DOM.Iterable","ESNext"]
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ]
}
```